# Dynamically loading Angular components in an Electron app

Tags: angular, electron

I am working on a kind of a pluggable app that works with Electron. Basically what I'm trying to achieve is to download Angular 2 component files as single .ts files (or .js files if latter is easier to do), compile and run them in the app when needed. Is loading the components in Electron main process and pass them to AppComponent before the bootstrapping starts an option?

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is writing a custom web server in the main process. You could setup a module system that loads whatever modules it needs and do any typescript compiling that is needed, then serve the result on localhost. This way every time an Electron window loads localhost you can load any modules on the fly.